# Magento 2 get url for specific store

Tags: magento2, url, geturl

I need to render inside admin grid preview url for specific store (depends on which store is selected). In Magento 1 the code is this:

```
$storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
if ($storeId == 0) {
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores(false, true);
    $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
}

$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getCode();        
$urlModel = Mage::getModel('core/url')->setStore($storeId);       
$url = $urlModel->getUrl(
    'banner/index/preview/id/'.$row->getId(), array(
        '_current' => false,
        '_query' => '___store='.$storeCode
   )
);
```

I ended up with this:

```
$storeId = (int)$this->request()->getParam('store');
if ($storeId == 0) {
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores(false);
    $storeId = current($stores)->getId();
}

$storeCode = $storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
```

But I don't find any code snippet for Magento 2 to migrate $urlModel part of code from Magento 1.

Tnx for any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get url with this method:

```
  \Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder

  $this->actionUrlBuilder->getUrl('route_path', $storeId, $code);
```

Answer (score 4):

inject storeManagerInterface in constructor

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
   .....
) {
   ...
$this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
}
```

Now you can GetUrl by command

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('routepath', ['_current' => true]);
```

Comment: You can do like this also. $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(), $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
            ->getStore($storeId)
            ->getBaseUrl();

Comment: yes but it forbidden. You should not get set data via objectmanager

Comment: Unfortunately this still shows url from admin:
`$this->_storeManager->getStore(2)->getUrl('routepath', ['_current' => true]);`

shows 

`http://dev.magento2.com/admin/routepath/index/index/key/9f0007091ce7cdd44b20f4020004bff6fa4157f25b4034c18efc71f328f861fb/`

Answer (score 0):

You can get url for specific store using an instance of StoreManagerInterface
it should be

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl();
```

Other types of url can be found here:
http://www.metagento.com/blog/base-url-in-magento-2.html

Comment: The question was not about base URLs.